# Change control color when it is disable

Tags: vb.net, colors, controls

I'm working on a very old application which was in VB6. Now It's in VB.NET and due to customers requirement, I need to change a button color when it is disable.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? I was wondering if there was an event I can catch to do that...

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: `someButton.Enabled = False` will set it to whatever the UI's disabled buttons look like. Would that suffice?

Comment: nope, I need to know exactly when the control is disabled. But I just saw the event enableChange, I'm gonna try that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the event EnableChange. Don't understand how I could miss that....